# How to group kubernetes ingress machines inside docker (in a grouped folder)?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

When I create the ingress inside the k8s it creates several machines ungrouped inside docker.
I am trying to declare in the yaml file something to make them stay together.
In docker yaml files i use a tag named 'name' that groups the machines together.
How to do that for k8s?
Thanks! S2
[image]

Tried name but did not works.
Expected to group the ingress inside a folder